# Oracle - drill down the records

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a table with services and each combination of the services have a specific cost amount.
I want to filter one service and get to know, what are the services one level to the left and then choose another service from that subpart, etc.

Please see an example picture:
On the left is the process of the "drill down" and on the right is the desired output. Please ignore the sum of the amounts (they are not correct).

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoIVM.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
id              INTEGER,
costcenter      VARCHAR2(20),
service_level1  VARCHAR2(40),
service_level2  VARCHAR2(40),
service_level3  VARCHAR2(40),
service_level4  VARCHAR2(40),
amount          INTEGER);

INSERT INTO test_table (id,costcenter, service_level1, service_level2, service_level3, service_level4, amount)
VALUES ( 1, '10016831', 'U00 COGNOS AL', NULL, NUll, NULL, 50000); 
INSERT INTO test_table (id,costcenter, service_level1, service_level2, service_level3, service_level4, amount)
VALUES ( 2, '10016832', 'EXADATA Basis', 'U00 COGNOS AL', NUll, NULL, 20000); 
INSERT INTO test_table (id,costcenter, service_level1, service_level2, service_level3, service_level4, amount)
VALUES ( 3, '10016833', 'SPLUNK','EXADATA Basis', 'U00 COGNOS AL', NULL, 15000); 
INSERT INTO test_table (id,costcenter, service_level1, service_level2, service_level3, service_level4, amount)
VALUES ( 4, '10016833', 'Linux Basis', 'SPLUNK', 'EXADATA Basis', 'U00 COGNOS AL', 30000); 
INSERT INTO test_table (id,costcenter, service_level1, service_level2, service_level3, service_level4, amount)
VALUES ( 5, '10016833', 'Linux Basis', 'Oracle Admin', 'EXADATA Basis', 'U00 COGNOS AL', 20000); 
COMMIT;
```

.
.
.

Thank you very much for your solution, it is working (I have tested with ~100 000 records), but with more data (~ 50 mil of rows) the performance is not so fast.

I would like to simplify it to have it like:

have a table with the service and its child service and sum(amount)
direction of the hierarchy is from left to right in the table
[See the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqjaZ.png)

Comment: read up on CONNECT BY

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to folow the desired output from the picture. Didn't quite catch it completely but here is what could be done. I'm sure you'll get to make it work...

```
WITH
    test_table AS
        (
          Select 1 "ID", '10016831' "COSTCENTER", 'U00 COGNOS AL' "SL_1", NULL "SL_2", NUll "SL_3", NULL "SL_4", 50000 "AMOUNT" From DUAL UNION ALL 
          Select 2 "ID", '10016832' "COSTCENTER", 'EXADATA Basis' "SL_1", 'U00 COGNOS AL' "SL_2", NUll "SL_3", NULL "SL_4", 20000 "AMOUNT" From DUAL UNION ALL 
          Select 3 "ID", '10016833' "COSTCENTER", 'SPLUNK' "SL_1", 'EXADATA Basis' "SL_2", 'U00 COGNOS AL' "SL_3", NULL "SL_4", 15000 "AMOUNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select 4 "ID", '10016833' "COSTCENTER", 'Linux Basis' "SL_1", 'SPLUNK' "SL_2", 'EXADATA Basis' "SL_3", 'U00 COGNOS AL' "SL_4", 30000 "AMOUNT" From DUAL UNION ALL
          Select 5 "ID", '10016833' "COSTCENTER", 'Linux Basis' "SL_1", 'Oracle Admin' "SL_2", 'EXADATA Basis' "SL_3", 'U00 COGNOS AL' "SL_4", 20000 "AMOUNT" From DUAL 
        )
--
-- S E R V I C E
SELECT
    'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", 
    Sum(AMOUNT) "AMOUNT"
FROM
    test_table
WHERE
    InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0
-- 
-- Result
-- SERVICE         AMOUNT
-- EXADATA Basis    85000
--
-- L E F T   1
SELECT 
    SERVICE "SERVICE",
    LEVEL_LEFT "LEVEL_LEFT", 
    Sum(AMOUNT) "AMOUNT"
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", CASE WHEN SL_1 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN COSTCENTER END "LEVEL_LEFT", AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", CASE WHEN SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_1 END "LEVEL_LEFT", AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0 
      UNION ALL
    SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", CASE WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_2 END "LEVEL_LEFT", AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0 
      UNION ALL
        SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_3 END "LEVEL_LEFT", AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0 
    )
WHERE
    LEVEL_LEFT Is Not Null
GROUP BY
    SERVICE,
    LEVEL_LEFT
--
-- Result
-- 
-- SERVICE          LEVEL_LEFT      AMOUNT
-- EXADATA Basis    10016832        20000
-- EXADATA Basis    SPLUNK          45000
-- EXADATA Basis    Oracle Admin    20000
--
-- L E F T   2
SELECT 
    SERVICE "SERVICE",
    LEVEL_LEFT "LEVEL_LEFT", 
    LEVEL_LEFT_2 "LEVEL_LEFT_2",
    Sum(AMOUNT) "AMOUNT"
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", 
                CASE WHEN SL_1 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN COSTCENTER END "LEVEL_LEFT", 
                CASE WHEN SL_1 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN Null END "LEVEL_LEFT_2",
                AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0
      UNION ALL
        SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", 
            CASE WHEN SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_1 END "LEVEL_LEFT", 
            CASE WHEN SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' And 
                 CASE WHEN SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_1 END  = SL_1 THEN COSTCENTER 
            END "LEVEL_LEFT_2",
            AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0 
      UNION ALL
        SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", 
            CASE WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_2 END "LEVEL_LEFT", 
            CASE WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' And 
                 CASE WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_2 END  = SL_2 THEN SL_1 
            END "LEVEL_LEFT_2",
            AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0 
      UNION ALL
        SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", 
                CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_3 END "LEVEL_LEFT", 
                CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' And 
                 CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_3 END  = SL_3 THEN SL_2
            END "LEVEL_LEFT_2",
                AMOUNT
        FROM    test_table
        WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0 
    )
WHERE
    LEVEL_LEFT Is Not Null
GROUP BY
    SERVICE,
    LEVEL_LEFT,
    LEVEL_LEFT_2        
--
-- Result
-- SERVICE          LEVEL_LEFT      LEVEL_LEFT_2  AMOUNT
-- EXADATA Basis    SPLUNK          Linux Basis    30000
-- EXADATA Basis    Oracle Admin    Linux Basis    20000
-- EXADATA Basis    SPLUNK          10016833       15000
-- EXADATA Basis    10016832        Null           20000
```

As you can see there is one row more then in the picture - it can be excluded but I didn't sure what should be the right condition to do it. You'll know. Regards..
If you are looking for LEVEL_LEFT_3 here is one of UNION SQLs dealing with EXADATA in column SL_3 (there is no EXADATA in SL_4). There where missing keywords. My mistake, sorry.

```
    SELECT  'EXADATA Basis' "SERVICE", 
        CASE WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_2 END "LEVEL_LEFT", 
        CASE WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' And 
             CASE WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_2 END  = SL_2 THEN SL_1 
        END "LEVEL_LEFT_2", 
  --  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --      L E V E L   3
  --
        CASE
            WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' And         -- IF driver in SL_3  
    --
                CASE 
                    WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' 
                    THEN SL_2 
                END  = SL_2  And -- And driver's 1st left  is equal to value of column SL_2     
  --
                CASE 
                    WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' And     
                        CASE 
                            WHEN SL_3 = 'EXADATA Basis' 
                            THEN SL_2 
                        END   = SL_2 
                    THEN SL_1 
                  END  = SL_1        -- And driver's 2nd left  is equal to value of column SL_1   
            THEN COSTCENTER       -- THEN take COSTCENTER    
        END "LEVEL_LEFT_3",
  --
  --  E N D   L E V E L   3
  --  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        AMOUNT
    FROM    test_table
    WHERE   InStr(SL_1 || SL_2 || SL_3 || SL_4, 'EXADATA Basis') > 0
-- 
--  R e s u l t
--
--  SERVICE       LEVEL_LEFT    LEVEL_LEFT_2  LEVEL_LEFT_3     AMOUNT
--  ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------ ----------
--  EXADATA Basis                                               20000 
--  EXADATA Basis                                               15000 
--  EXADATA Basis SPLUNK        Linux Basis   10016833          30000 
--  EXADATA Basis Oracle Admin  Linux Basis   10016833          20000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I got it almost complete except for this composed case
 `CASE WHEN SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' And 
                 CASE WHEN SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_1 END  = SL_1 THEN COSTCENTER 
            END "LEVEL_LEFT_2"`
Does this mean, that when SL_2 is equal to 'EXADATA Basis' AND SL_1 = SL1 THEN COSTCENTER?

Comment: It is like this:  CASE WHEN SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_1 END is "LEVEL_LEFT" and case you are asking for means IF SL_2 = 'EXADATA Basis' And LEVEL_LEFT = SL_1 THEN LEVEL_LEFT_2 Is COSTCENTER.  So, this nested case is actually reffering to LEVEL_LEFT

Comment: It is a kind of dynamic relative positioning driven by EXADATA Basis. So if driver is in SL_4 one step left is SL_3 and two steps left is SL_2, If it is in SL_3 then one step left is SL_2 and two steps left is SL_1. If in SL_2 then one step left is SL_1 and two steps left is COSTCENTER. If in SL_1 then one step left is COSTCENTER and two steps left is NULL.

Comment: Inner case is here because there are two rows (possibly more) where EXADATA is in the same column (SL_3) and this inner case solves the confusion in which row we are currently looking (the one with SPLUNK or Oracle admin in SL_2 - which is one left or "LEVEL_LEFT" from SL_3) Regards...

Comment: Yes, I got it, and for other levels to left, can I continue like this?
LEVEL_LEFT_3
`CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' and 
                    CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' And 
                     CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_3 END  = SL_3 THEN SL_2
                    END = SL_2 then SL_1 
                END level_left_3`

Comment: LEVEL_LEFT_4
`CASE when  SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' and
                    CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' and 
                    CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' And 
                     CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_3 END  = SL_3 THEN SL_2
                    END = SL_2 then SL_1 
                END = SL_1 then costcenter
                END level_left_4`

Comment: Yes, you should add another AND  to check if you are on the right record. So like there is a check for LEVEL_LEFT there should be a check for LEVEL_LEFT_2 also. There is a posibility that some rows could have the same data in more then one column.  The logic is IF driver is in SL_4 and his LEVEL_LEFT is equal to value of SL_3 AND his LEVEL_LEFT_2 is equal to value of SL_2 THEN SL_1.

Comment: I have updated the answer with LEVEL_LEFT_3 code.

Comment: There is a missing keyword error at the line with code for LEVEL_LEFT_3
`CASE WHEN SL_4 = 'EXADATA Basis' THEN SL_3 END  = SL_3 THEN SL_2  And`

Comment: Answer edited - it works now. There is no EXADATA in SL_4 so I put Level 3 column in SQL  dealing with EXADATA in column SL_3 (there are 2 rows).

Comment: If yyou want the records to be ordered like in your picture just add ORDER BY SERVICE, LEVEL_LEFT_3, LEVEL_LEFT_2, LEVEL_LEFT at the end. Regards...